# Mocking DynamoDB.DocumentClient's constructor with Jest and Typescript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, aws-sdk-js

In my TypeScript application, I have wrapper functions over AWS SDK DynamoDB's `DocumentClient` functions and I want to write some unit tests for these wrapper functions. The wrapper functions are implemented as follows:

```
dynamodb.ts


import DynamoDB from 'aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb'
import AWS from 'aws-sdk/global';


const config: DynamoDB.Types.ClientConfiguration = {
  httpOptions: {
    connectTimeout: 500,
    timeout: 1000,
  }
}

const service = new DynamoDB(config);
const ddb = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ service });

export const putItem = wrap(ddb.put.bind(ddb));

const wrap =
  <I, O>(fnc: (args: I) => AWS.Request<O, AWS.AWSError>) => (args: I) => {
    return fnc(args).promise()
      .then(result => {
        log(result);
        return result;
      });
  };
```

I prefer to not perform any actual end to end put/get in the DDB tables and just mock the AWS SDK functions. However I'm facing some issues with mocking the constructors for `DynamoDB` and `DynamoDB.DocumentClient`.

Currently my unit test file looks like this:

```
dynamodb.test.ts

import * as sut from "../dynamodb"
import DynamoDB from "aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb";


jest.mock("aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb", () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    const documentClient = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        const awsSdkPromiseResponse = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
        const putFn = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({promise: awsSdkPromiseResponse}))
        return {
          put: putFn,
          get: putFn,
          delete: putFn,
          batchGet: putFn,
          batchWrite: putFn,
          query: putFn,
          scan: putFn,
          update: putFn,
          transactGet: putFn,
          transactWrite: putFn
        }
    })
    return { DocumentClient: documentClient };
  });
});

test('AWS.DynamoDB is called', async() => {
  await sut.putItem({
    TableName: 'test',
    Item: {
      pk: 'test_pk',
      sk: 'test_sk',
      email: 'test@test.com'
    }
  })
  expect(DynamoDB).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```

Running this test gives me an error like so:

```
TypeError: _dynamodb.default.DocumentClient is not a constructor
```

It seems like `DocumentClient` is a static property located in the namespace `DynamoDB` and what I'm trying to do above in the mock of `DynamoDB` is define `DocumentClient` as an instance property of `DynamoDB` class. I know this is not correct and I've scoured the internet to search for something similar but couldn't find anything.

The problem is also that I would like to mock the constructors for both `DynamoDB` and `DocumentClient` class in my test file. I found an [article](https://dev.to/elthrasher/mocking-aws-with-jest-and-typescript-199i#dynamodb) similar to what I'm trying to do but the manual mocking here is also not helping. Through this, I'm not able to mock both the constructors for `DynamoDB` and `DocumentClient`

I am very new to TypeScript and maybe I'm doing something completely stupid. Any pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

```js
const dynamoPromise = jest.fn();

jest.mock('aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb');

  // Mock the default export and named export 'foo'
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    DocumentClient: jest.fn(() => ({
      batchWrite: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
        promise: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(dynamoPromise),
      })),
    })),
  };
});

//later in a test case
dynamoPromise.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.reject(new Error('For testing purposes DynamoDB fails.')));
```